# PySpark: Recalculating Columns and Comparing Results - Precision calculation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

While working with PySpark, I came across an interesting observation. I was querying a database and extracting data with the goal of recalculating certain columns. However, I noticed that even the simplest calculations, such as a product, wouldn’t always match the expected result.

For example, given columns **colA**, **colB**, and **colC**, I calculated the product of these three columns and stored the result in a new column, **ABC**. I then compared this result to the correct value, stored in **colABC**, and calculated the difference between the two in a column called **dif**.

Interestingly, whenever **dif** was not equal to 0, the difference was always one of a few fixed values: 2.00, 0.375, etc. I even tried performing the same calculation in an Excel sheet and stored the result in a column called **excel**.

Here’s a sample of my data:

| colA | colB | colC | ABC | colABC | dif | excel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.011434 | 0.0045 | 3,885,697,280.00 | 19,993,076.00 | 19,993,078.00 | 2.00 | 19,993,078.21 |
| 0.028841 | 0.0045 | 2,178,074,880.00 | 28,268,034.00 | 28,268,036.00 | 2.00 | 28,268,035.93 |
| 0.011434 | 0.0045 | 3,832,956,928.00 | 19,721,712.00 | 19,721,714.00 | 2.00 | 19,721,713.28 |

To calculate **ABC**, I used a user-defined function (UDF) that looked like this:

```
def abc(id, A, B, C):
    if id== 'textA':
        abc = 0.0
    elif id== 'textB':
        abc = A
    elif id == 'textC':
        abc = A * B 
    elif id== 'textD':
        abc = 0.9725 * B * C
    elif (id == 'textE') or (id== 'textF'):
        abc = A * B * C
    else:
        abc = A * B * C

    return round(abc * 100, 11)

abc_udf = udf(abc, FloatType())
```

Once I had my data in a PySpark DataFrame, I generated the **ABC** column like this:

`df = df.withColumn('ABC', abc_udf('id', 'a', 'b', 'c'))`

I had previously defined the schema of my DataFrame to include a column for **ABC** with a `FloatType` data type.

`StructField("ABC", FloatType(), True)`

I tried changing the data type but it didn't work. The thing is that there are other UDFs that use p.norm and other statistical functions and so the required data type has to be Float.

Comment: Try using [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) type in your UDF? eg. `return Decimal(A) * Decimal(B) * Decimal(C)`

Comment: I'll try it, but the thing is that in the code there are other UDFs and some of them have to be FloatType since they use np.norm and this function is only posible in floats